# Content Assist not working as expected on Eclipse

Tags: android

These are the specs:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional x86
- IDE: Eclipse Juno 4.2 (for Java Developers)
- ADT: Version 20
- SDK: 7

I'm creating an XML layout, and after dragging a ImageView to a FrameLayout, it all works as expected.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android1:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:src="@drawable/logo_splashcreen" />

</FrameLayout>
```

What I noticed, is that it is using `android1` instead of `android`.

If I try to add a new parameter to the ImageView, via the `Ctrl+Space` it throws me the [image] error.

Is it normal? Never happened to me before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the

```
  xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

line, which seems to be a useless duplicate for

```
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Then, replace all '**android1:**' by '**android:**' strings in your file.

Comment: Oops, haven't noticed that line there, oh god... Thanks for your answer, solved my problem! :)